# changing boot priority to external disk

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, external-hdd, process-priority

I just installed xubuntu. I dual booted it, my main os is windows 7. I installed ubuntu onto a external hdd and is my second boot priority so since i use it the most, it is a hassle to change every time i log onto my computer.

My question is this: If i go an change the boot priority to automatically boot to ubuntu, will this have any affect on my windows 7, which is installed on the hard drive. It would be ideal to be able to boot directly into ubuntu, but i dont want to risk ruining my windows to do so.  I know how to change the boot priority, I needed to do that for the dual boot, but I want to make sure setting it up like this wont hurt anything.

Thank you for you responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will have no affect on your Windows hard drive. It does not change anything on the hard drives itself but just where the motherboard should look for a OS to load.